# How to match elements of a BigQuery array with dates by starting from a given date?

Tags: sql, arrays, google-bigquery

How can I match elements of an array with dates by starting from a given date until end of the array for every day?

e.g:

The table I have:

| numbers | start_date |
| --- | --- |
| [1, 2, 3] | 2022-01-01 |

SQL to create this table:

```sql
SELECT [1, 2, 3] as numbers, CAST('2022-01-01' AS DATE) AS start_date;
```

The table I expect to have from the table above:

| number | matched_date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 |
| 2 | 2022-01-02 |
| 3 | 2022-01-03 |

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select number, date(start_date) + offset as matched_date
from your_table, unnest(numbers) number with offset
```

if applied to sample data in  your question - output is

[image]